# SQL Query to find all columns except purely numeric or blank values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a column in sql table where you can store anything (character, numeric, special character, blank space or a combination of all). I want to find or have a select statement which returns all values except those containing purely numeric values or blank spaces only.

ex if I have values

1. ABCD
2. abcd
3. 1234
4. AB12
5. "?" (blank space)
6. 12AB
7. ab@!
8. @!12
9. !@#$

it should give all rows except 3rd and 5th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where ISNUMERIC(col) != 1 and len(rtrim(col)) >= 1
```

full example:

```
create table #t1 (col varchar(50))

insert into #t1 (col) values('ABCD')
insert into #t1 (col) values('abcd')
insert into #t1 (col) values('1234')
insert into #t1 (col) values('AB12')
insert into #t1 (col) values(' ')
insert into #t1 (col) values('12AB')
insert into #t1 (col) values('ab@!')
insert into #t1 (col) values('@!12')
insert into #t1 (col) values('!@#$')

select col    
from #t1    
where isnumeric(col) != 1 and len(rtrim(col)) >= 1

drop table #t1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC(isnull(field,1)) != 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

**`ISNUMERIC` does not always return correct results.** It is better to use `TRY_CAST/CONVERT` to specify what you would like for the conversion:

```sql
WHERE TRY_CAST(field AS real) IS NULL -- or you can put int, bigint, numeric(18,2)
```